# For inside other for in javascript not works correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.users.data.length; i++) {
      var user = vm.items.users.data[i];
      user.goals_by_brands = [];
      var brands = [];
      vm.items.brands.data.forEach( function(element, index) {
        brands.push(element);
      });
      console.log("brands", brands)
      console.log("vm.items.brands.data", vm.items.brands.data)
      brands.forEach( function(brand) {
        brand.goals_by_months = [];
        brand.user = user;
        constants.MONTHS.forEach( function(month) {
          brand.goals_by_months.push({goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0});
        });
        user.goals_by_brands.push(brand);
      });
```

}

I put this lines :

```
var brands = [];
      vm.items.brands.data.forEach( function(element, index) {
        brands.push(element);
      });
```

But I tried too with clone array (slice() function) and it do the same.

In brands array and in vm.items.brands.data array, appeared the same; the last user in vm.items.users.data array.

I dont know why..

I would like to do this:

- I have array with users. -> vm.items.users.data
- I have array with brands. -> vm.items.brands.data
- I have array with months. -> constants.MONTHS

I would like to add array with this object -> {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0} to each brand 12 times (one each month).
Then this brands, I would like to add to each user ->

```
[
      {
        id: "user1",
        name: "user1",
        goals_by_brands: [
          {
            id: "brand1",
            name: "brand1",
            goals_by_months: [
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0},
              {goals: [], total_month_goal: 0, total_month_accumulated: 0}
            ]
          }
        ]

    }]
```

So I would like to add user into each brand object of goals_by_brands.

Sorry about my english.

Comment: *"it doesnt work"* - remember to state what your code is supposed to do and what the actual result/problem is.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you explain this "In brands array and in vm.items.brands.data array, appeared the same; the last user in vm.items.users.data array."

Comment: when I do for, in user object that I would like add, appeared the last one user of vm.items.users.data array @SharjeelAhmed

Comment: Do you mean it is only taking the last user? Can you show me JSON final output console.log(vm.items.users.data)

Comment: You can paste your JSON here http://pastebin.com/index.php

Comment: How I can do this? vm.items.users.data is an array and when I do JSON.stringify show TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136844/discussion-between-sharjeel-ahmed-and-oihi08).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with your code is that you have the "brands" references rather than a copy of brands. Since you are changing the main reference, the brands keeps getting over written, hence please make this change in your loop.

```
var brands = []; 
vm.items.brands.data.forEach( function(element, index) { 
brands.push(element); //This pushes the reference which remains the same.
});
```

change this push line to

```
var newBrand = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element))) //Make a deep copy of the element
brands.push(newBrand)
```